# How to generate multiple Tuples or String combinations of a custom Java Object

Tags: java, oop

I'm trying to run a program that would load test my backend application. The program should generate all combinations of tuples of a particular class given the cardinality of each attribute of the class.

For example consider this class

```
public ClassA{
  String name;

  String id;

 String kind;
}
```

The use case is that the user will input cardinality of each attribute of this class and the output should List of Strings/Tuples of those values. For eg: User inputs `name` with cardinality `100`, `kind` with cardinality `10` and `id` with cardinality `1000`. Basically range of attributes generated will be `name_0` to `name_99`, `kind_0` to `kind_9`, `id_0` to `id_999`. So there will be a total of `1000*10*100` combinations.

This should generate

```
 < name_0, id_0, kind_0>
 < name_0, id_0, kind_1>
 < name_0, id_0, kind_2>
            .
            .
            .
            .
 < name_0, id_1, kind_0>
 < name_0, id_2, kind_0>
 < name_0, id_3, kind_0>
            .
            .
            .
            .
 < name_1, id_0, kind_0>
 < name_2, id_0, kind_0>
 < name_3, id_0, kind_0>
            .
            .
            .
            .
```

What is the best way to do this? From both an implementation and design perspective ? Any examples would definitely help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
IntStream.range(0, nameCount)
    .flatMap(n -> IntStream.range(0, idCount)
        .flatMap(i -> IntStream.range(0, kindCount)
            .map(k -> new ClassA("name_" + n, "id_" + i, "kind_" + k))))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```